# Nextauth requires a SECRET property

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, jwt, next-auth

After checking the documentation it says that .env or [..nextAuth.js] file you should set a secret property in the configuration.

[Error documentation to nextAuth](https://next-auth.js.org/errors#no_secret)

.env

```
NEXTAUTH_URL = "http://localhost:3000"
NEXTAUTH_SECRET_KEY="test"
```

[...nextAuth.js]

```
  secret: "test",
  jwt: {
    secret: "test",
    encryption: true,
    maxAge: 5 * 60,
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
  },
```

However, this is a requirement only if you are in production, but I am not.
How to fix this error and set it on development, not in production?

Comment: The environment variable for the secret is `NEXTAUTH_SECRET`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah the new environment variable is called simply `NEXTAUTH_SECRET`.

Also when this is set, you can avoid setting the `secret` and `jwt.secret` values separately in the configuration.